# How to select a single row when grouping by column and by max date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data which I would like to filter so I only get only one row based on the grouping of the first column and select the max date

co2 contains unique values

```
col1 | col2 | date

 1   |  123 | 2013
 1   |  124 | 2012
 1   |  125 | 2014
 2   |  213 | 2011
 2   |  214 | 2015
 2   |  215 | 2018
```

so the results I want are:

```
 1   |  125 | 2014
 2   |  215 | 2018
```

I've tried using a few examples which I found on here (as below) as well other group by / distinct / max(date) but with no luck

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the partition in the `row_number()` to only partition by `col1` but keep the order by `date desc`:

```
select col1, col2, date
from 
(
  select col1, col2, date,
    row_number() over (partition by col1 
                       order by date desc) as rn
  from yourtable
) x
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87390/2).

Since you were partitioning by both `col1` and `col2` you were getting unique values for each row. So it would not return the row with the max date.

Comment: [Well then](http://cf.chucklesnetwork.agj.co/items/1/4/0/4/i-dont-always-upvote_but-when-i-do-i-have-to-t.jpg)

Comment: @Bluefeel it says illegal use of long data type on the last line

Comment: @Stan I am not sure I understand the error.  Where are you getting the error?  Here is a working Oracle demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87390/2.  What version of Oracle?  What are the datatypes on your table?

Comment: @Bluefeet, actually it looks good, not sure why it errored when I first ran it. started again and it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

I prefer bluefeet's method, but here is an equivalent using MAX:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.date
FROM yourtable t
    JOIN (
        SELECT col1, MAX(date) maxDate
        FROM yourtable
        GROUP BY col1
    ) t2 on t.col1 = t2.col1 AND t.date = t2.maxDate
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87390/9) (borrowed from other post)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select * from yourtable where date in 
(select max(date) from tab group by col1);
```