# not a single-group group function with MAX in select

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select sg_gameno, Max(sg_Year), sg_end, sg_hostcity, country_olympic_name
  from Summergames s, Country co
 where s.country_isocode = co.country_isocode
```

Don't know whats wrong with this. I want to get the lastest year. Should i use MAX or something else.

Comment: you need to get the information of the latest year?

Comment: Yes i want to get the latest year

Answer (score 4):

If you want to aggregate one column (`sg_year`) and to not aggregate others, you need a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
Select sg_gameno, Max(sg_Year), sg_end, sg_hostcity, country_olympic_name
  from Summergames s, 
       Country co
 where s.country_isocode = co.country_isocode 
 group by sg_gameno, sg_end, sg_hostcity, country_olympic_name
```

is syntactically valid.  Whether it provides you the results you want is another question-- you'd need to tell us what your tables look like, what data is in them, what result you want, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can't have aggregate functions and individual columns in the SELECT list, unless the individual columns are included in GROUP BY clause.

You can use RANK or DENSE_RANK function to rank the records based on thet year and then select the from the resultset the top ranked rows.

```
select * from (
    select sg_gameno, sg_Year, sg_end, sg_hostcity, country_olympic_name,
           rank() over (order by sg_year desc) as ranking
      from Summergames s, Country co
     where s.country_isocode = co.country_isocode
     )
  where ranking = 1;
```

You can also use following query to get the same result. You will have to select the one that performs best for you.

```
select sg_gameno, sg_Year, sg_end, sg_hostcity, country_olympic_name
  from Summergames s, Country co
 where s.country_isocode = co.country_isocode
   and sg_Year = (select max(sg_Year)
                    from Summergames s, Country co
                   where s.country_isocode = co.country_isocode);
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821811/how-to-select-a-single-row-when-grouping-by-column-and-by-max-date?rq=1) question. This has different possible solutions.

Comment: ^ can you please help me out