# Select max from calculated column alongside other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has columns ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, all of type NUMBER.

I want to find the MAX of a function on FIELD1 and FIELD2, and display that alongside the ID.

I try

```
SELECT ID, MAX(SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2)) AS CALC
FROM TABLE;
```

But it returns `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`.

I tried the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886155/not-a-single-group-group-function-with-max-in-select#), but they have their own errors.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID, SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2) AS CALC,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CALC DESC) AS RANKING
    FROM TABLE
)
WHERE RANKING = 1;
```

gives the error

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'OGC_CALC'
```

and so does

```
SELECT ID, SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2) AS CALC
FROM TABLE
WHERE CALC = (
    SELECT MAX(CALC)
    FROM TABLE
);
```

Using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0.

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below two queries.

```
SELECT ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2) AS CALC
FROM   TABLE WHERE SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2)= (SELECT MAX(SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2)) FROM TABLE);
```

Or,
Suggested by Aleksej without using aggregate or group by function.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT ID, 
               SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2)
        FROM TABLE
        ORDER BY 2 DESC
        )
    WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Initial query,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID, 
           MAX(SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2)) AS CALC
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ID
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Comment: Whoops sorry. I wrote out that second example wrong. It should've been SELECT ID, MAX(SQRT(FIELD1 + FIELD2) AS CALC. But anyway, no, your answer is not what I'm looking for. I want a *single* result returned, the highest one from the table. The GROUP BY in your example prints out hundreds of results.

Comment: @JimCullen - Notice that this queries do different things, for example the first one can return more than one row, the second one can not

Comment: Will the first one return more than one answer if there are multiple rows tied for highest value of CALC?

Comment: Yes the first query will return the records with the maximum value for CALC, hence if there are multiple records for the max value then all the records will be fetched. The secord query will give only the record even if there are multiple IDs for max value for CALC. Its upto you to decide which one to use for your requirement

Comment: @hemalp108 - Are you sure you need the MAX and GROUP in the second query? given that you use an ORDER, isn't aggregation unuseful?

Comment: @Aleksej: You are right. The query will work without Aggregate function and Group by clause also. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single value, with the maximum `sqrt(field1+field2)` among all the values of ID, these are two possible ways:

```
select *
from (
      select *
      from yourTable
      order by sqrt(field1 + field2) desc
     )
where rownum = 1           

select id, field1, field2
from (
        select t.*,
               row_number() over ( order by sqrt(field1 + field2) desc) as rn
        from yourTable t
      )
where rn = 1
```

Notice that if you have more than one ID with the same, maximum value, this will pick one of them randomly.